# How to select a MailItem not in the Explorer CurrentView

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

When trying to programmatically select a MailItem to be shown in the ActiveExplorer, I get the "Cannot select or deselect the item because it is not available in the current view" exception.

I have a TaskPane in Outlook showing a list of emails based on some user specified search criteria and I am trying to allow the user to right-click on a single email (in the TaskPane) and show it in the Explorer window. This works great when the user currently has their inbox open/selected in the Explorer and they attempt to show an email found in their inbox. However, if they try to show an email found in their sent box, then it throws the "Cannot select or deselect the item because it is not available in the current view" exception.

I am updating the view by setting the ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder property to the selected email's parent folder and this seems to be the best way to do this. I confirmed that the CurrentFolder and CurrentView properties are changing to what they should be and that the Explorer view does indeed change, but I still get the exception when I try to select the item.

I originally just tried to change the CurrentFolder, then AddToSelection, but moved the AddToSelection to an event handler thinking that it was happening to fast. Of course, that didn't fix the problem.

```
    public void SetExplorerSelection(string emailID)
    {

        //Get Outlook namespace
        var oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        //Get the Active Explorer
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer activeExplorer = oApp.ActiveExplorer();

        //Clear the current selection
        activeExplorer.ClearSelection();

        //Get the Mail Item
        MailItem mailItem = oNS.GetItemFromID(emailID);

        if (activeExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(mailItem))
        {
            //Show the item in the Explorer
            activeExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem);

            return;
        }
        else
        {

            //* indicates items that were added to TRY to fix the problem

            //*Send selected item to public var
            currentMail = mailItem;

            //*Get the Current View
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.View cView = activeExplorer.CurrentView;

            //*Check the initial states of CurrentFolder and CurrentView
            Debug.Print("Folder (from): " + activeExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name);
            Debug.Print("View (from): " + cView.Name);

            //*Create event handler for ViewSwitch
            activeExplorer.ViewSwitch += new ExplorerEvents_10_ViewSwitchEventHandler(Explorer_ViewSwitch);

            //Change the Current Folder being viewed in the Explorer
            activeExplorer.CurrentFolder = mailItem.Parent as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder;

            //*Reset/Apply changes to the CurrentView
            cView = activeExplorer.CurrentView;
            cView.Reset();
            cView.Apply();

            //activeExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem);

        }


    }

    //*ViewSwitch Event Handler
    public void Explorer_ViewSwitch()
    {

        //Get Outlook namespace
        var oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        //Get the ActiveExplorer
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer activeExplorer = oApp.ActiveExplorer();

        //Get the CurrentView
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.View cView = activeExplorer.CurrentView;

        //Check the current states of CurrentFolder and CurrentView
        Debug.Print("Folder (to): " + activeExplorer.CurrentFolder.Name);
        Debug.Print("View (to): " + cView.Name);

        //Add the item to the selection
        //***This is where the exception occurs***
        activeExplorer.AddToSelection(currentMail);

        //Reset the public var
        currentMail = null;

    }
```

As I mentioned, I confirmed that the Debugs are showing the correct information (switching from inbox to sent box) and that the view itself is changed (sent items folder is selected) in the Explorer before getting the exception. If I continue running the code and try again with the same email now that the view is already set as the sent box, it works fine and properly pulls up the sent email.

Comment: Is the message visible in the list when you attempt to select it?

Comment: If the inbox folder is currently selected and an email in the inbox folder is selected, then it works. If an email in the sent items folder is selected (and the inbox folder is still selected in the explorer), then I get the exception, but this is after the code has already selected the sent items folder.

Comment: After the folder is selected, the message list is populated asynchronously, you might have to wait until that happens.

Comment: Ok, that is definitely the problem. I added a wait method just to test it out and that works as expected, but I would certainly prefer a way to execute upon completion of the message list being populated. Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: I can only think of using Explorer.FolderSwitch event if you are setting the Explorer.CurrentFolder property.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public void SetExplorerSelection(string emailID)
{

    //Get Outlook namespace
    var oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
    var oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

    //Get the Active Explorer
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer activeExplorer = oApp.ActiveExplorer();

    //Clear the current selection
    activeExplorer.ClearSelection();

    //Get the Mail Item
    try
    {
        MailItem mailItem = oNS.GetItemFromID(emailID);

        if (activeExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(mailItem))
        {
            //Show the item in the Explorer
            activeExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem);

            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int flag = 0;
            foreach(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myDestFolder in oNS.Folders[mailItem.ReceivedByName].Folders)
            {
                activeExplorer.CurrentFolder = myDestFolder;
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.View tmp in myDestFolder.Views)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        activeExplorer.CurrentView = tmp;
                        activeExplorer.ClearSelection();
                        activeExplorer.AddToSelection(item);

                        tmp.Reset();
                        tmp.Apply();

                        flag = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if(flag ==1 )
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It is deleted message");
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! The `oNS.Folders[mailItem.ReceivedByName].Folders` bit is causing trouble as it throws an "Array index out of bounds" exception. This is caused by the `mailItem.ReceivedByName` being "null". However if it is an email that I sent, then the "ReceivedByName" is going to cause issues anyway since it will be trying to look at another user's folders, right? I tried "SenderName", but that doesn't work either. What I need is `mailItem.Parent.Parent` to get back to the main folder, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Just in case this helps someone, I was able to make it work by simply replacing `oNS.Folders[mailItem.ReceivedByName]` with `mailItem.Parent`, i.e. there is no need to iterate through all folders. `mailItem` can already tell u about its folder. Just switch to it and then call `AddToSelection`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @장인수's answer, here is my revised version that works:

```
void SetExplorerSelectionToMailItem(string mailItemId)
{
  //Get the Active Explorer
  Explorer activeExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer();

  //Clear the current selection
  activeExplorer.ClearSelection();

  //Get the Mail Item
  try
  {
    MailItem mailItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(mailItemId); 

    //if this mailItem resides in the same folder the one currently selected in the explorer view
    if (activeExplorer.IsItemSelectableInView(mailItem))
    {
      //Show the item in the Explorer
      activeExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem);
    }
    else
    {
      //otherwise, select the folder first
      activeExplorer.CurrentFolder = mailItem.Parent;
      foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.View tmp in mailItem.Parent.Views)
      {
        try
        {
          activeExplorer.CurrentView = tmp;
          activeExplorer.ClearSelection();

          //and now select and display the mailItem
          activeExplorer.AddToSelection(mailItem);

          tmp.Reset();
          tmp.Apply();
          break;
        }
        catch
        {
          continue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch
  {
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("It is deleted message");
  }
}
```